# Why is the array shown as 1D instead of 2D but the table works?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

</head>

<form name="formular">
<label>Zeilen eingeben:     
        <input id="inpZeile" name="inpZeile" type=number value="2">
</label>
<label>Spalten eingeben:
        <input id="inpSpalte" name="inpSpalte" type=number value="2">
</label>
</form>
<button type="button" onclick="machTabelle(document.forms.formular.elements.inpSpalte.value, document.forms.formular.elements.inpZeile.value)" id="MachTabelle">Tabelle erstellen</button>
</html>



<script src="testen.js"></script>

var table ='';
function machTabelle(x,y)
{
    var myArr = new Array(x);
    for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++)
    {
        myArr[i] = new Array(y);
        
    };
    console.log (myArr);

        for(var i=0; i<x; i++)
        {
        table += '<tr>';
            for(var j =0;j<y;j++)
            {
                table += '<td>' +j+ '</td>';
            }
        table += '<tr>';
        }   
document.write('<table border=1>' +table+ '</table>');
}
```

I changed things around but it always returns a 1D array instead of a 2D , using the same code for array only as a snippet worked.

The goal is to make array and table, taking user input for size, and of course later make a table with the content of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table works as you are first looping the input `x` and then looping the input `y`

**Note** that you have no variable `table` in the function. You can add for example `var table = "";` and that `myArr` is not used in the generating of the table.

---

When you create an array `Array(y)` the `y` from the *input* is a string. (Note the order of the parameters of the function and the input fields.)

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array

For example `machTabelle('3', '2')` see the inline comments:

```
// Array with index 0 has the value of the input "2" as you are passing a string
var myArr = new Array(y); 

// loop 1 time, as there is 1 item
for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++) { 
    
    // set index 0 of the array to a new array with the y input of "2"
    myArr[i] = new Array(y);
}
```

The `myArr` is a 2d array instead of 1d as you are wrapping an array in an array:

```
myArr = [
  [
    "2"
  ]
]
```

Comment: Thank you! sovar myArr = new Array(parseInt(x));
    for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++)
    {
  myArr[i] = new Array(parseInt(y));
        
    };

Comment: @Yuuuhu Yes, did it work out? You can also set the radix to 10 for parseInt `new Array(parseInt(y, 10));`

Comment: yes worked perfectly fine :) now im onto event listeners, what do you mean by radix

Comment: @Yuuuhu See the second parameter (radix) of [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: ok thanks :) haha yes ok that radix thing is good to know... guess decimal was default